# Getting a list of assemblies needed by application

Tags: .net, reflection, assemblies, dependencies, nsis

Is there a way of getting all required assemblies (excluding the .net framework) for a .net project into a folder ready to be packaged into an [nsis](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) as setup file?

I've tried writing a small console app that uses reflection to get a list of dlls but have got stuck with finding a foolproof way of determining if a dll is from the .net framework or not.

The answer could be a simple switch in Visual Studio to output all dependencies, or a standalone app that can do it, or a plugin for Nsis, or some information on reflection that I've missed.

Comment: In terms of the foolproof way of determining if a dll is from the .net framework or not, the best I can do is the using the Codebase property of the Assembly object, which for mscorlib is "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework, however it isn't for all .net framework assemblies.

Comment: You want to be careful with this, depending on what your NSIS installer is for. You might find that you accidentally include a DLL in your installer which you don't have a license to redistribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio (2005 at least - what I'm using right now), each reference that you have associated to a project has a property called "Copy Local", this can be set to true/false. When true it will copy the dll's for you into the current configuration directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [NDepend](http://www.NDepend.com) for this. Download it, build a new NDepend project, drag&drop your assemblies in the Application Assemblies data grid view, and you'll see NDepend resolving instantly the tier assemblies needed by your set of Application Assemblies.

You can also provide a list of folders to tell NDepend where to look. If a tier assembly can't be found, then NDepend will mark it as not found, which I think is a valuable information.

Answer (score 0):

[Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com) is what you need. Or maybe [Depends.Net](http://www.netomatix.com/Development/DependsNet.aspx)

Comment: Dependency Walker does not resolve assembly references (see http://www.dependencywalker.com/faq.html)